# PySpark - Extract Max Value for Column for 24 Hour Window, Then Drop Duplicates

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to find the `max_value` for `value` for each `id`. Only the max value needs to be recorded once and at the first record for the day on `date`

```
+---+-------------------+-----+----------+
| id|               date|value| date_only|
+---+-------------------+-----+----------+
| J1|2016-10-01 00:00:00| Null|2016-10-01| 
| J1|2016-10-01 01:00:00|    1|2016-10-01|
| J1|2016-10-01 12:30:30|    3|2016-10-01|
| J9|2016-10-06 00:00:00|    2|2016-10-06|
| J9|2016-10-06 09:20:00|    4|2016-10-06|
| J9|2016-10-06 09:20:00| Null|2016-10-06|
+---+-------------------+-----+----------+
```

Desired DataFrame:

```
+---+-------------------+-----+----------+---------+
| id|               date|value| date_only|max_value|
+---+-------------------+-----+----------+---------+
| J1|2016-10-01 00:00:00| Null|2016-10-01|        3|
| J1|2016-10-01 01:00:00|    1|2016-10-01|     Null|
| J1|2016-10-01 12:30:30|    3|2016-10-01|     Null|
| J9|2016-10-06 00:00:00|    2|2016-10-06|        4|
| J9|2016-10-06 09:20:00|    4|2016-10-06|     Null|
| J9|2016-10-06 09:20:00| Null|2016-10-06|     Null|
+---+-------------------+-----+----------+---------+
```

**What I tried:**

This only keeps the groupby variables and excludes all other variables (100s) from the new dataframe)

```
df = df.groupBy("id", "date_only").agg(max("max_value").alias("max_value1")).sort('date_only')
```

Sample code I've tried below. There are 96 rows per date, but sometimes it doesnt match up. Is there a another function like pandas DateTime or do I need to remove the rowsbetween arg?

```
w = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy(F.col("date_only").cast('long'))

main = main.withColumn('max_value', F.max("value").over(w))
```

I also tried, however it did not change the duplicate values in the column:

```
df.groupBy("ID", "Date").agg(first("max_value").alias("max_value"), count("*").alias("cn")) \
  .withColumn("max_value", when(col("cn") > lit(1), lit(None)).otherwise(col("max_value")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two WinSpecs with their default frames (below from [doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window)):

> Note When ordering is not defined, an unbounded window frame (rowFrame, unboundedPreceding, unboundedFollowing) is used by default. When ordering is defined, a growing window frame (rangeFrame, unboundedPreceding, currentRow) is used by default.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F
w1 = Window.partitionBy('id') 
w2 = Window.partitionBy('id', F.col('date').astype('date')).orderBy('date')
# set up the first records on each day regardless if or not the date is ending with `00:00:00`
df.withColumn('max_value', F.when(F.row_number().over(w2)==1, F.max('value').over(w1))).show()
+---+-------------------+-----+----------+---------+                            
| id|               date|value| date_only|max_value|
+---+-------------------+-----+----------+---------+
| J1|2016-10-01 00:00:00| null|2016-10-01|        3|
| J1|2016-10-01 01:00:00|    1|2016-10-01|     null|
| J1|2016-10-01 12:30:30|    3|2016-10-01|     null|
| J9|2016-10-06 00:00:00|    2|2016-10-06|        4|
| J9|2016-10-06 09:20:00|    4|2016-10-06|     null|
| J9|2016-10-06 09:20:00| null|2016-10-06|     null|
+---+-------------------+-----+----------+---------+
```

Edit: based on comment, to adjust all dates ending with `00:00:00` to max_value:

```
df.withColumn('max_value', F.when(F.col('date') == F.date_trunc('day', 'date'), F.max('value').over(w1))).show()
```

Comment: thanks for providing feedback above. I have found this works for only the first day of the column for every id (i.e. if there is `2016-10-02` for id `J1` it will create a null there and all the way down the dataframe.

Comment: on the first date of every `00:00:00` (i.e. `2016-10-01 00:00:00`, `2016-10-02 00:00:00`, `2016-10-03 00:00:00`, etc)

Comment: ok, what is the datetype of `date` column, is it a StringType or TimeStampType?

Comment: it is a TimeStamp

Comment: if rows for a date do not have `00:00:00`, do you also want to change that to max_value, if that is the case, will need to add `date_only` column to partitionBy of w2

Comment: I adjusted the w2 so that it cover days when `00:00:00` is missing and you still want to set max_value on their first record of the day.

Comment: Hi, @Starbucks, your new question looks the same as this one, just add `date_only` to partitionBy of w1 and w2. for example: change `w1 = Window.partitionBy('id', 'date_only')`, `w2 = Window.partitionBy('id', 'date_only').orderBy('date')`